# Add Redis USER & PASS to Django channel layer

Tags: django, websocket, redis, django-channels

I'm trying to deploy my WebSocket project on the server (for example Heroku).
and I have a Redis server that has a USER & PASS.
I want to add this to my Django channel layer.
I need your help.

This is my *channel layer*:

```py
 CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'USER': 'spadredis-zxs-service',
        'PASSWORD': '9zghygpri84f8vl',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('188.40.16.3', 32281)],
        },
    },
}
```

This is my error in **terminal** :

```
await conn.execute('ping')
aioredis.errors.AuthError: NOAUTH Authentication required.
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/lobby_room/ [127.0.0.1:42812]
```

[image: :)))]

Comment: I think your redis is not configured to accept auth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that OP is using the `channels-redis` package in order to use Redis as a channel layer, that's good.

Assuming Redis is running in the host `188.40.16.3` and the port `32281`, I suggest OP to remove `USER` and `PASSWORD` from `CHANNEL_LAYERS` and add it in the `CONFIG` hosts (as [suggested here](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/164#issuecomment-220513297)) like

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [("redis://spadredis-zxs-service:9zghygpri84f8vl@188.40.16.3:32281")],
        },
    },
}
```